# i want extract matched words from string and return it including 2 words before it and 2 words after it (if found)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search, preg-match-all

I want do a trick like most search engines seems to do.

Let's say that I have this string:

```
$str = "Hello Mr. Ben From the UK, nice to meet you";
```

I want a regular expression to search for two words or more, the words in this case are *to* and *Ben*

I can do it using `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all("#[\w+]*(to|Ben)+\w*#isx", $str,$matches);
```

and it works fine, but I need to **return** the matched words in a phrase for each one. 
For example the word *to*, I want return it matching  this format *nice **to** meet*, i.e. wrapped in the surrounding words

I want to do the same for *Ben* ,

I can do it using `explode`, `preg_match`, `loop` so I think that it's better to do it by `preg_match_all`.

**PS:** I have another quick question, can I do this "trick" but using `sql query` when fetching the data from my database?

Thank you.

Comment: [Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did it by this regex

```
preg_match_all("#(.){0,15}(to|Ben)+(.){0,15}#isx", $str,$matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER , 1);
var_dump($matches);
```

share answer for all